# Does the bounded context concept exist only in strategic DDD? Or it can be also be equal to the physical border of a service, in tactical DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

If we have two different services (that share the same ubiquitous language) communicating each other by one message broker or through APIs, do we have necessarily two different bounded contexts?

In other words, the physical border of a service is always the frontier of a bounded context?

### Bounded Contexts only in Strategic DDD?

One possibility is that a bounded context can contain multiple services, that are physically divided. In this idea, the bounded context would be only the frontier of the ubiquitous language, and would exist only in the strategic DDD.

### Bounded Contexts in Strategic and Tactical DDD?

Other possibility is that the physical border is also a bounded context delimitation and when two services communicate using a message broker or APIs they are two different bounded contexts, even though they are part of the same subdomain and share the same ubiquitous language.

Comment: The purpose of the bounded context is to identify entities that operate fairly independently, which don't need other entities in performing operations or transactions. Communication is expensive. So, if two services need to constantly communicate to fulfill some goal, maybe the design is not right.